How to dynamically adjust the vertical space between two QTableViews in a QVBoxLayout?
I'm working on a Qt application where I have two QTableView widgets (tableAView and tableBView) placed inside a QVBoxLayout. Each table can dynamically change the number of rows (using a QAbstractTableModel), and their content is always different. Sometimes, tables might even have no content at all. However, I'm facing an issue where, if tableAView reduces its number of rows (vertical size decreases), the vertical space between tableAView and tableBView does not adjust accordingly. It seems to remain static, leaving a large, unwanted gap.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
QWidget *header = new QWidget(this);
QWidget *options = new OptionsWidget(this);
QWidget *textWidget = new TextWidget(this);

QTableView *tableAView = new QTableView;
QTableView *tableBView = new QTableView;

tableAView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
tableBView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(header);
layout->addWidget(options);
layout->addWidget(tableAView);
layout->addWidget(tableBView);
layout->addWidget(textWidget);

I've tried setting different size policies, but I can't seem to get the layout to adjust the space between the tables dynamically based on their content.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to make the vertical space between the tables adjust dynamically?
Thanks in advance!

QTableView inherits from QAbstractScrollArea. Hence, I believe if this can be achieved at all, it will result in convoluted custom code. How about a QSplitter instead of a QVBoxLayout?
